# On screenshot of failed testcases how to mark or make rectangle on that failed part in screenshot?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, ui-automation, allure

I'm writing automation tests and In conftest.py file I have configuration for setup and teardown of browser, capture screenshots on failed test cases.
But, I'm stock on making mark on screenshots where testcases failed

Here is my code:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True, tryfirst=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
    return rep


@pytest.fixture()
def log_on_failure(request, setup_teardown):
    yield
    item = request.node
    driver = setup_teardown
    if item.rep_call.failed:
        allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name=f"Fail{request.function.__name__}_{time.strftime('%y_%m_%d_%H_%M')}", attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)


@pytest.fixture(params=["chrome"], scope="function")
def setup_teardown(request):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    driver.get(read_configuration("info", "site_url"))
    request.cls.driver = driver
    driver.maximize_window()
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

Test class:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup_teardown", "log_on_failure")
class TestMain:
    @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.NORMAL)
    def test_check_header_items(self):
        main = MainHeader(self.driver)
        main.website_icon_is_displayed()
        main.chatai_is_displayed()
        main.search_field_is_displayed()
        main.search_button_displayed_and_able()
        main.login_button_displayed_and_able()
```

I'm using pytest, allure report, python 3.11 and POM pattern

My script works well but I can't find solution with best practice for adding mark or rectangle in captured screenshots

Comment: And where is your test?

Comment: Do no post additional information to the question in comments, just edit the question